# loading div using jquery inside shadowbox, IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, shadowbox

I am opening a page inside a shadowbox. But then when user clicks on a button, it loads the second div in the same page from a different page using jQuery.ajax. It works for FF,chrome and safari but not for IE8.

```
`function open_shadowbox_div_view(){

Shadowbox.open({
         content:  
                   $("#div1").html(),  
                   player:     "html",                                                    
                   height:     420,    
                   width:      750 ,
                  options:{
                       onFinish: function(){  

                       } ,
                          onClose: function(){  }

                   }



    });

}



function newOccFunction(contract){


    var site_url = "page.php?var=";?>"+var;

    jQuery("#div1").load(site_url,function(){open_shadowbox_div_view();});


}'
```

this opens the first div.
Then there is a button in that page that loads up a div in the same page.php
Button onclick function
    'function filter(){

```
    var site_url = "page2.php";

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : site_url,

        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            jQuery("#sb-player #div2").html(data);
            alert(jQuery("#sb-player #div2").html());//This returns null

        },
        failure: function(){
            alert("fail");
        }

    });
}'
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Than you

Comment: I don't understand this piece of code : `var site_url = "page.php?var=";?>"+var;` What do you want to do ? Shouldn't you at least escape the " ?

Comment: site_url has the code that contains content for the div. Sorry for the ?, i had to edit piece of code for company privacy, there was a php tag which calls a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the content i am trying to load into a div is inside the first page in shadowbox, we don't have to use #sb-player but all the div tag that is nested. It only affect in IE, therefore you can just do.

To clarify,
if it is like

```
 <div id="sb-player">
 <div id="main_box"><div id="second_box"></div></div>
```

then you can load content in "second_box" by doing this:

```
 jQuery("#main_box #second_box").load(url);
```

Hope it helps for those who have wasted hours figuring this.